# mutiple content in button in blend 4 WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i add mutiple content in button like text and image ? in blend 4 WPF C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Panel as Content of the `Button`.
Here's an example with a `StackPanel` with two children, `TextBlock` and `Image`

```
<Button Width="75" Height="100">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Some Text"/>
        <Image Source="C:\C1.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```